# Can't get ejs value into script variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Whenever I attempt to set a variable within a script to be equal to an array rendered using ejs I get 'Invalid are unexpected token'.

Here is the snippet:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var list = <%= events.slice(0) %>;
    </script>
```

Originally I had it set to:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var list = <%= events %>;
    </script>
```

But I receive the same error. I was pretty certain you could render an ejs file that contains script tags and set the ejs variable to a variable within the script tag. Am I wrong?

Events is an array of event models for a calendar.

Comment: What do you get in rendered html?

Comment: try this.events inside script tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is what you are looking for:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var list = <%-JSON.stringify(events)%>;
</script>
```

Comment: This did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add script tags. Just put your code in html

Here is a plain example

index.ejs

```
<script>

//just call the events variable

for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++){
    var myEvent = events[i];
    //handle the event
 }

//then use the variables outside the script tag after you are done with all the handling

</script>

<ul>
<li><%=myDefinedVariable%></li>
<% var name = "Jake" %>
<li><%=name%></li>

<%for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){%>
<li><%=name%></li> // puts li in the ul 10 times
<%}%>
</ul>
```

Comment: I understand but I was using the script to create the calendar

Comment: You still don't have to include your ejs javascript in the script tags, just place them outside and create the calender there @CollinDeSoto

Comment: Well I need each event to be listed on the correct day when each day blog is created. If the ejs var is outside the script I can't dynamically list each event on the correct day. If I don't use a script tag I will end up with a lot of <% tags

Comment: then define them in the script tags, and whenever you will post them to the html just use it like this @CollinDeSoto

Comment: I forgot to say the events are being pulled from mongodb

Comment: does it change anything? just use your code in script tag, you don't have do ejs scripting to use the event in a script tag, then you can just use ejs if you ever wanna display anything on the html *outside* the script tags

Comment: What I'm saying is the events list is being passed from the back end.

Comment: res.render('events', {events: events});

Comment: check the update @CollinDeSoto it is that simple? why are you so confused? you can use the `events` variable anywhere